# What am I doing wrong to get segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I'm trying to replicate the function strstr. When my function finds `to_find` in `str` it works accordingly. If `to_find` is not in `str` I get segmentation fault, even though I created a condition to `return NULL;` if my `str` gets to `'\o'` without getting any matches.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char    *ft_strstr(char *str, char *to_find)
{
    char    *to_find_copy;
    char    *str_copy;

    to_find_copy = to_find;
    str_copy = str;
    while (*to_find_copy != '\0' || *str_copy != '\0')
    {
        if (*to_find_copy == *str_copy)
        {
            to_find_copy++;
            str_copy++;
        }
        else
        {
            to_find_copy = to_find;
            str++;
            str_copy++;
        }
    }
    if (*str_copy == '\0')
        return NULL;
    return (str);
}


int main(void)
{
    char str[50] = "Yesterday I went to the store";
    char to_find[50] = "Z";
    char *ptr;

    printf("\nString 1:   %s\nString 2:   %s\n", str, to_find);

    ptr = ft_strstr(str, to_find);
    
    printf("\nEncontrou:    %s\n", ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
String 1:   Yesterday I went to the store 
String 2:   Zer
zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

It should return NULL.
I believe I must be overwriting the memory of an array but I don't understand why.

PS. I can only use 25 line in the function at max.

Comment: Please edit your code and fix the formatting and indention, it's all over the place.

Comment: The non-match means you are passing a `NULL` pointer for `printf()` to dereference. Some implementations kindly output `(null)` but they are not obliged to. Find out if the function *is* returning `NULL` by a specific test of the returned value.

Comment: Oh, you are using `||` instead of `&&`. Then it outputs `(null)`.

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: I didn't get seg-fault on my system... it works fine and returns (null).  By the way, I also get (null) if I assign to_find "ter" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this code. Your code didn't give segmentation fault on my system, but it doesn't give correct results. It always returns NULL

I will return String "NULL" instead of NULL...

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *ft_strstr(char *str, char *to_find) {

  int found = 0;
  char *return_value = str;

  while (found == 0) {
    if (*to_find == *str) {
      to_find++;
      str++;
    } else {
      str++;
      return_value++;
    }
    if (*to_find == '\0') {
      found = 1;
      return return_value;
    }

    if (*str == '\0') {
      return "NULL";
    }
  }
}


int main(void) {
  char str[50] = "Yesterday I went to the store";
  char to_find[50] = "Zer";
  char to_find_2[50] = "ent";
  char *ptr;

  printf("\nString 1:   %s\nString 2:   %s\n", str, to_find);
  ptr = ft_strstr(str, to_find);
  printf("\nFound:    %s\n\n", ptr);
  printf("\nString 1:   %s\nString 2:   %s\n", str, to_find_2);
  ptr = ft_strstr(str, to_find_2);
  printf("\nFound:    %s\n", ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
> ./strstr

String 1:   Yesterday I went to the store
String 2:   Zer

Found:    NULL


String 1:   Yesterday I went to the store
String 2:   ent

Found:    ent to the store
```